# Howto find a maximum value for attribute pairs in an MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with log data, of this form:

```
Date        Time    Device  Configuration
01.01.2012  12.00   8193    12345
01.01.2012  12.15   8193    12345
01.01.2012  12.35   8193    22375
01.01.2012  12.37   7191    32335
```

I need the maximum Configuration, on each Day, for each device:

```
Date        Device  Configuration
01.01.2012  8193    22375
01.01.2012  7191    32335
```

I can create a cross product of Dates-devices to get all Date-device combinations,
 but how do i find the **maximum configuration** for **each Date-Device pair**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by both Date and Device, get the MAX and you're done.

```
SELECT Date, Device, MAX(Configuration) AS Configuration
FROM logData
GROUP BY Date, Device
```

Comment: The title says "MySQL" so you probably want to use backticks to quote instead of brackets.

Comment: @muistooshort: Or just remove the quotes altogether, since MySQL permits `Date` to be an unquoted identifier.

Comment: @muistoshort Done. Missed the MySQL in the title. Thanks for adding the tag and comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
select `date`,`Device`,max(Configuration) as MaxConfig from logData
group by `date`,`Device`
```